# passing item id value via javascript in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

i have to send this 'data-curated-id' from my href of calling modal to its  modal and set the value of hidden field 
i.e. 
have to set 'value' of modal form to the value of data-curated-id ='<%= item.id %>' from my href link

here is modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form role="form" action="<%= duplicate_curated_items_path %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="data_curated_id" type="hidden" value='' />
```

here is code of calling modal

```
<a href ="#" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-default"    id = "myButton" data-curated-id ='<%= item.id %>' >
                      Duplicate
```

===javascript code====

```
 $(document).on("click", ".tabledit-edit-button", function () {
        var Idimp = $(this).data('data-curated-id');
        $(".modal-content #data_curated_id").val(Idimp)
        $('#myModal').modal('show');  
    });
```

i tried this javascript code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct key with [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. Remove `data-` then use `camelCase`

[Dataset API Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-htmlelement-dataset)

> For each name in list, for each U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) in the name that is followed by a lowercase ASCII letter, remove the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) and replace the character that followed it by the same character in ASCII uppercase.

*Use*

```
 var Idimp = $(this).data('curatedId');
```

*instead of*

```
 var Idimp = $(this).data('data-curated-id');
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tabledit-edit-button", function() {
  var Idimp = $(this).data('curatedId');
  console.log(Idimp)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-default" id="myButton" data-curated-id='1'>1</a>
```

Comment: I think like this $(this).data('curated-id');

Comment: but its data-curated-id, i cant see curatedId anywhere.   is there some format for .data

Comment: value is not getting assigned to 'value' attribute of modal , it ran succesfully but when i inspect it in browser , value is still empty in modal form